# Push button switch plus 10 LED's

Tags: led, switches, button

How to insert a push button switch in this circuit?

6 Volt Power Supply 10 LED's 10 resistors.
I can do it with just one resistor and 10 LED's.
I have a 6 pin push button switch.

[image: Diagram]

Here's my circuit of 10 LED's with each one having its own
resistor. The question is how to wire a push button switch
for on/off the ten lights.

I can use one resistor and ten led's, but that's should have
been avoided (diffrent voltage drop of each led)
Here's the picture of my circuit.

My power supply is 6 Volts (4 AA batteries).

Comment: Could you add a schematic? We have an awesome on-site schematic editor, which you can start-up with Ctrl-M.

Comment: You might also mention what you would like to do with the push button, and what type of switch you have (six pin tells some things, but leaves out plenty)

Comment: You still haven't said what the pushbutton is supposed to accomplish and what type of pushbutton you have.  6 pins is unusual for a plain pushbutton, so it is probably more complicated than that.  Given the refusal to answer all the questions, I don't see the point in re-opening this question.

Comment: Ever notice how the lights shine when the battery is connected, but if even so much as one connection to one of the two battery terminals is broken, the lights stop shining? That should give you an idea about wiring the switch.

Answer (score 1):

The push-button switch referenced is a latching DPDT switch, PG707110D01. One sketchy, very low resolution datasheet was found, which is given below:

[image: Pushbutton]

The switch part number mentioned (in a comment now deleted) indicates the "Push to Latch" subtype.

The contacts, as per this diagram, will be closed (conducting) between pins 2 and 3, and between pins 4 and 5, when the button is latched down. Clicking it to latch in the up position will open the connection between those contacts.

Hence, one way to wire up the switch connection would be thus:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flFx4h.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>